# Application of Backtracking algorithm to find minimum number of semester to graduate

Tags: c, arrays, backtracking

[image]
I'm taking input from a file , which contains

1. No of courses and max allowed course per semester
2. All Course name(5 alphanumeric max)
3. couse name,Offered sem, number of prereqs, Prereq courses.
4. -1 and -1 at the end
   The output will be the minimum number of semester to complete all courses.

This is my code, so that you know I've done work. My code is compiling and executing, but not showing the number of sems to complete courses.
Please tell me where I'm doing wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

char garbage[12][6];
char courseIdentifier[12][6],prereqIdentifier[12][5][6];
char semOffered[12];
bool done[12];

bool allDone(int);
bool donePrereq(int,int);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("graduate.in","r");
    int n,m,p;
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        strcpy(courseIdentifier[i],"");
    }
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            strcpy(prereqIdentifier[i][j],"");
        }
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&n,&m);// take n,m
    while(n != -1)
    {

        if( !(1<=n && n<=12) || !(2<=m && m<=6) )
        {
            printf("Wrong input");
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) //the list of offered courses
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s",garbage[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s %c %d",courseIdentifier[i],&semOffered,&p);//the name of course, sem,no. of prereqs
            for(j=0;j<p;j++)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%s",prereqIdentifier[i][j]);
            }
        }

        int sem=1;
        char semNow = 'F';
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            done[i]=false;
        }
        while(!allDone(n))
        {
            int count=0;
            //while(count<=m)
            //{
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    if( (semOffered[i]==semNow || semOffered[i]=='B') && donePrereq(p,n))
                    {
                        done[i] = true;
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            //}
            sem++;
            if(semNow=='F')
            {
                semNow='S';
            }
            else if(semNow=='S')
            {
                semNow='F';
            }
        }
        printf("minimum number of semesters = %d\n",sem);
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&n,&m);// take n,m
    }
    return 1;
}

bool allDone(int n)
{
    bool returnBool=true;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        returnBool = returnBool && done[i];
    }
    return returnBool;

}

bool donePrereq(int p,int n)
{
    bool returnBool=true;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(prereqIdentifier[i][j],courseIdentifier[j]) ==0 )
            {
                printf("prereq matched\n");
                returnBool = (returnBool&&done[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return returnBool;
}
```

Comment: Please consider changing the question title.

Comment: if this is a homework assignment please state so

Comment: In addition to the above comments, what kind of output does your program currently give you?

Comment: @Oak I don't think it matters now whether this is a homework assignment.  The question is reasonably clear and the code posted shows that the O/P has made reasonable efforts to solve their problems before posting here.

Comment: It is not giving any output, I think it is in infinite loop....

Comment: If all you're seeing is "it's not producing output", you need more information.  If you're skilled with debuggers, hook one up to your code, and step through it.  Barring that, there's the uglier-but-easier solution - add a lot of printfs to your code.  Specifically, add it anywhere program flow may change (ie `if`, `for`, `while`, and `switch` statements), and at the start and end of each function.  You can print out variables of interest or just numbers - something to show you the program flow.  This may help you find the problem, or at least give us more details to help you.

Comment: Please don't write/post code with commented out lines such as `//while(count<=m)`. It just adds confusion to your post. Also, you are not being concise. You just throw to us your whole program and ask us to debug it. How much are you paying?

Comment: Closing as off topic - show more effort.

Comment: Can you distill this down to a concise example of the problem you have?

Comment: Run your code in a debugger, and step through it.  If there is an infinite loop, it will be ***OBVIOUS***.  *(using debuggers is **not** optional)*

Comment: Looking at the title one would be clearly confused but looking at the question, I don't think its a question to be put on hold, just because of the title, this is seriously a platform for experts as I heard, apparently no room for beginners or learners.

Comment: @interjay Thanks.  I'll delete my incorrect comment.

Comment: Do you really want to / have to use C for this?

Comment: @tripleee No, I don't need to use C, but I'm comfortable with C

Answer (score 1):

When you are scanning your input for the information about each offered course here:

```
        fscanf(fp,"%s %c %d",courseIdentifier[i],&semOffered,&p);
```

The `&semOffered` parameter is incorrect. You will need to provide the pointer to a `char`. Since `semOffered` is an array of `char`, you probably meant to store it into the indexed position:

```
        fscanf(fp,"%s %c %d",courseIdentifier[i],&semOffered[i],&p);
```

This does not fix your program, but it does allow the program to complete.