# Using of fscanf() and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

I want to take input from a file and display it exactly onscreen.

I'm taking input from a file, which contains:

1. No of courses and max allowed course per semester
2. All Course name(5 alphanumeric max)
3. course name, Offered semester, number of pre-requisite, pre-requisite courses.
4. -1 and -1 at the end.

[image: input]

[image: Unexpected output]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

char garbage[12][6];
char courseIdentifier[12][6],prereqIdentifier[12][5][6];
char semOffered[12];
bool done[12];

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("graduate.in","r");
    int n,m,p[12];
    int i,j,k;
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&n,&m);// take n,m
    while(n != -1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) //the list of offered courses
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s",garbage[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s %c %d",courseIdentifier[i],&semOffered[i],&p[i] );//the name of course, sem,no. of prereqs
            for(j=0; j < (p[i]) ;j++)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%s ",prereqIdentifier[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%s %c %d ",courseIdentifier[i],semOffered[i],p[i]);
            for(j=0; j < (p[i]) ; j++ )
            {
                printf("%s ",prereqIdentifier[i][j]);
            }
            printf("%s\n");
        }
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&n,&m);// take n,m
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

The output is not correct. Where am I doing wrong, using of arrays or `fscanf()`?

Comment: We'll need to see some code please.

Comment: So let me get this strait, you want to read a file and then output it and that's it?

Comment: *"The output is not correct"* - What output do you get and what output do you expect? Which line produces the wrong output? - Btw. this looks very similar to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575696/application-of-backtracking-algorithm-to-find-minimum-number-of-semester-to-grad, and the advice given there still applies: **Run your code in a debugger, and step through it!**

Comment: @ColeJohnson actually I want to save the the data in the variables and    want to use them later, but I found out that I can't save the data properly...

Comment: @MartinR No need to copy paste the previous suggestion, I did so and found out that this is the part I'm going wrong and mentioned this specifically, what is the purpose of debuggin when I know this is the erreneous part?

Comment: @IRock: The purpose of debugging is that you single-step through your code and inspect the contents of the variables. Then you can tell exactly at what point the program does not behave as you expected. I cannot see in your question that you did this, perhaps I overlooked something.

Comment: @MartinR they told me either to debug or to use printf everywhere
I tool printf option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
printf("%s\n");
```

will print some random garbage -- based on whatever string happens to be in a particular register.  Looks like in your case it consistently prints an additional copy of `courseIdentifier[i]`

Comment: @IRock printf expects you to pass an additional cstring as a parameter when you use "%s": printf( "%s\n", maFancyString ); You should take a look at some docs on printf and friends.

Comment: @IRock Why are you using printf("%s\n")?. printf("%s\n") without arguments will print random string. You are not going to print anything  right then y %s der? JUst use printf("\n") if you wanna print a line.